# BarChartView xAxis label doesn't display all labels

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I have a `BarChartView` with 31 bars, and thus 31 labels. I add everything and set it up according to examples and it works as it should - except that the BarChartView only displays each 3rd label. So I try to print out 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,..., 30, 31 but It prints 1, 4, 7, 11,..., 31. How can I change this? I don't even need to print all labels, all I really need is the first and last label, so 1 and 31, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to set this.

I've tried setting the label to `nil` for each bar that is not the first or the last, but that doesn't do anything either. I believe the reason it prints each 3rd label is because it can't fit them all in, correct? My setup for the `BarChartView` is:

```
    barChartView.descriptionText = ""
    barChartView.noDataTextDescription = ""
    barChartView.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = false
    barChartView.xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
    barChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    barChartView.xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = true
    barChartView.drawBordersEnabled = false
    barChartView.leftAxis.enabled = false
    barChartView.rightAxis.enabled = false
    barChartView.legend.enabled = false
    barChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .Bottom
    barChartView.xAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    barChartView.xAxis.labelFont = UIFont(name: timesNewRoman, size: barChartView.xAxis.labelFont.pointSize)!
    barChartView.dragEnabled = false
    barChartView.highlightEnabled = false
    barChartView.scaleXEnabled = false
    barChartView.scaleYEnabled = false
```

and I add the `xValues` like this:

```
for (index, value) in plotData.enumerate() {
        var xValue: String?
        xValue = index == 0 || index == plotData.count-1 ? "\(index + 1)" : nil


        barChartData.addXValue(xValue)
        let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(value: Double(value), xIndex: index)

        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, for x axis, there is `axisLabelModulus` and `AxisModulusCustom` to control the modulus when displaying x axis labels.

By default it's automatically calculated.

```
public var axisLabelModulus = Int(1)
/// Is axisLabelModulus a custom value or auto calculated? If false, then it's auto, if true, then custom.
/// 
/// **default**: false (automatic modulus)
private var _isAxisModulusCustom = false
```

you can use `setLabelsToSkip()` to set how many labels to be skipped.

```
/// Sets the number of labels that should be skipped on the axis before the next label is drawn. 
/// This will disable the feature that automatically calculates an adequate space between the axis labels and set the number of labels to be skipped to the fixed number provided by this method. 
/// Call `resetLabelsToSkip(...)` to re-enable automatic calculation.
public func setLabelsToSkip(count: Int)
```

Comment: @Wingzero In which version of library this feature is included ?

Comment: @Wingzero Can you tell me in which class these function and properties are written (Thanks)

Comment: you should be able to search

Comment: @Wingzero I looked for this but could not find it. Using 2.2.5

Comment: @AbdulRehmanWarraich that's simply not true. check your library fisrt

Comment: I look it in every class but couldn't found these. I found "public func setLabelCount(count: Int, force: Bool) " function AxisBase.swift .

Comment: @AbdulRehmanWarraich you should check your library code with github branches then

Comment: Kindly tell me the library version where I can find it.

Comment: @Wingzero I downloaded fresh copy of Master from github and searched for " public func setLabelsToSkip " function but could not find it. (AbdulRehman)

Comment: you should catch up with what the library us doing. you should use chart2.2.5 branch...

Comment: For the record, this functionality is not available in the current version (3.4.0).

Answer (score 7):

In

```
pod 'Charts', '~> 3.0'
```

use this:

```
public func setLabelCount(count: Int, force: Bool)
```

Comment: To display all labels set to the count of your data points. You can put a high number like `9999999` and one label will be used for each of the data points. But this doesn't work if you have grouped sets and you want one label per set.Is there a simple way like the old way to do this or updating the number of labels every time my data changes is the only way to go?